# regex replacement word not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I have an incomplete xml file that needs a quick fix. Simplified, here is how it is coming in:

```html
<positions><date></date><cust></cust><date></date><cust></cust></positions>
```

Here is what it needs to look like to process downstream:

```
</date><cust></cust></position><position><date></date><cust></cust></position></positions>
```

I thought this would work:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b<date>\b");
findFirstTag = r.Replace(findFirstTag, "<position><date>");
Regex x = new Regex(@"\b</cust>\b");
findFirstTag = x.Replace(findFirstTag, "</cust></position>");

Console.WriteLine("Converted by regex: " + findFirstTag + "\n");
```

Nothing changed. Anyone?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Have you tried using an xml reader instead?

Comment: no time for xmlreader--need a quick fix for a production process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), but there isn't one before the "<" or after the ">". A word boundary occurs on the change from a word character to a non word character or from a non word character to a word character. Here you want to have it between two non wordcharacters "><" this is always false.

Just remove it and you should be fine:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"<date>");
```

and

```
Regex x = new Regex(@"</cust>");
```

Comment: Brilliantly done @stema--that fixes my woes so i can turbo fix these prod files. Much appreciated.